# Verify if Active Directory windows authorization is correctly set up in MVC5 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication

I have begun working on a small web-app for an internal site. The default View will be a simple table listing all data from an Oracle Database with several Textboxes for search criteria. There will also be a view for "Management" of the data in this table, which I would like to lock down via Active Directory credentials.

Referencing the ASP.Net article, "[Autheticating Users with Windows Authentication](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs)", I have attempted to implement this. As instructed in the article, I modified my main **Web.config** for **Windows** authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
    </httpModules>
```

Since I am currently developing through the ASP.NET Development Web Server included with Visual Studio, I didn't see the need ot enable NTLM authentication or IIS features at this time (feel free to correct me if I've overlooked something major).

I then continued following the article by setting up my **Controllers\HomeController.cs** similar to the example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using InventoryTracker.Models;
using InventoryTracker.DAL;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace InventoryTracker.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        InventoryTrackerContext _db = new InventoryTrackerContext();
        public ActionResult Index(INV_Assets defModel)
        {
            return View(defModel);
        }

        [Authorize(Roles="IT Group")]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Roles="SomeDomain\\aguy")]
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

What I found strange though, was that when I went to log in for the first time, I was first forced to register? After registering I can now log in, but I'm unsure if the `[Authorize]` attributes are actually taking effect.

For instance, when I go to the `About()` page which is currently set up for `Roles="IT Group"` (previously used `Roles="Managers"`), instead of being there since I am part of the IT Group, I am instead asked to log in again?

Can anyone offer some insight into what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of an app running Windows Auth is to log you in automatically. However, if you attempt to access some part of the site that your user is not authorized to, it can fall back to an actual login form to give you the opportunity to "upgrade" your permissions by logging into another account than the one you're running with on the system. Long and short, if you're getting thrown to a login screen that's because your user account doesn't have the necessary permissions.